# saving the hash output to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have this output hash

```
output= {:user_id=>"1", :project_id=>"8", :task_id=>"87", :date=>"07/04/2017", :time_spent=>"1100", :comment=>"july 4th"}
```

I am trying to save this into the database by doing 
Model.create!(output)  in the model but not able to save it. I am getting this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
```

Below is what is shown in the server log

```
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "entries" ("user_id", "project_id", "task_id", "date", "time_spent", "comment", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["project_id", 8], ["task_id", 87], ["date", "2017-04-06 20:00:00.000000"], ["time_spent", "1100.0"], ["comment", "jully 4th"], ["created_at", "2017-07-04 10:57:30.040744"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-04 10:57:30.040744"]]

   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
```

I am not  able to make out what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try this and see what is the error in rollback
    `model =Model.create!(output)`
    `puts model.errors.inspect`